# Single download file upload mechanism

Tags: php

Sorry for the relatively vague title, I couldn't think of anything else.

So in short what I'm asking for is what would be an optimal (least resource intensive) way of creating a simple file upload service that would delete the file after the first download. Can be PHP or anything else (as long as it's relatively easy to implement). It's basically for streaming screenshots for a single user.

The first thing that comes to mind is simply doing a regular upload and then doing a readfile() followed by an unlink(). sendfile is obviously out of the question since then I don't have a way of executing code after the file has been transferred. But readfile() doesn't seem like such a good idea.

I wouldn't mind installing a separate daemon or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

1. Get the temporary path to the file from the `$_FILES['tmp_name']`
2. Move it to a non-guessable server location (as in `uploads/file{random_numbers}.extension`
3. Store the information in a DB

Upon visiting `yoursite.tld/view.php?id={unique id that's <> file{random_numbers}`:

1. `SELECT path FROM TABLE WHERE token = 'UNIQUE ID ABOVE' AND downloaded = 0`

   1.1 IF there is a row in the DB, we get the path and then we set `downloaded = 1` in the DB
   1.2 ELSE we don't do anything further
2. INCLUDE the file on the page with a non-regular header so that it gets downloaded
3. Run a cron-job every `x` minutes to clear out files that aren't needed anymore - cron won't be able to delete a file that's currently being transmitted to the user (as far as I know, as it would still be "in use").

Hopefully you'll be able to follow my logic and implement it as planned.

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind installing a separate daemon you can install [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). You might set it up so that it would remove outdated files every `n` minutes.